# Changes from the ansible docker_container to the community.general.docker_container

Tags: docker, ansible, containers

When [the new Ansible documentation of the `docker_container` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docker_container_module.html) states

> To use it in a playbook, specify: `community.general.docker_container`.

How do we specify this on the playbook YAML? It used to be `docker_container` but I think it may have changed.

Comment: Aren't the [examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docker_container_module.html#examples) talkative enough to you? The task will be `- community.general.docker_container:` when it was `- docker_container:` because, now, all Ansible task are aligned and contains a namespace, a collection; then only the name of the module.